# get_absolute_url and url template tag

Tags: python, django, url

I would like to understand what is the benefit to use the get_absolute_url call instead of the url template tag.

**get_absolute_url:**

```
class Project(models.Model):

   @permalink
   def get_absolute_url(self):
       return ('view_project', (), {'project_id': self.pk})

<a href="{{ project.get_absolute_url }}"> {{ project.name }}</a>
```

**url template tag:**

```
<a href="{% url 'view_project' project.pk %}"> {{ project.name }}</a>
```

Thank you for your help,

Julio

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only clear advantage is that you can change the name of the url for that model without having to rewrite all your templates. Also, if you define a `get_absolute_url` function (you don't have to use it in your templates, though), that provides some additional benefits like adding a `View on site` button in Django's admin or providing a fallback success url for class-based modelform views.

However, `get_absolute_url` and in general urls for models is an [ongoing point of discussion](https://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/ReplacingGetAbsoluteUrl).

Comment: I think he is right, you can do a lot implementing the function..
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/#get-absolute-url

Answer (score 0):

I find it easier to manage all my url in template if there are "located" only into one place, ie in the model. So everytime I need an url related to an object I use get_absolute_url.

But since Django 1.5 *@permalink* is deprecated, you must use **reverse()** instead. Please [check documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/models/instances/#the-permalink-decorator)